# Is it possible to somehow install sample data after the install?

Tags: installation, sample-data

I overwrote the media and skin folders on the magento installation with the sample data's skin and media  folders. I also ran the query against the database. Now I have a problem because "There has been an error processing your request", and I can't access Magento site any more. What can I do to pull through the sample data, and have my Magento working again?

Comment: Try truncating `core_resource` and flushing caches. This will make all setup scripts run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned the original media and skin folders (fortunately I saved them just in case). After that, I copied and merged the potential extra content from the sample data, in media and skin folders. Works fine now. And with sample data content.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible

```
sudo php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Run this command in Magento root dir